# N is not defined (Global Present)

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm currently doing a project that is a random generator that reads on an excel file and select a data randomly but as I develop my code I get the following error:

```
line 19, in RandomG
    L2 = Label(r2, text=edata).grid(row=3, column=1).grid(rowspawn=3, sticky=S)
NameError: name 'edata' is not defined
```

I have been told once to use "global" so the variables applies to all functions
but it still gives me the error.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import xlrd
import random
import os

creds = 'Python file.txt' # This just sets the variable creds to 'tempfile.temp'

def RandomG():
    global r2
    r.destroy()
    rootA.destroy()
    r2 = Tk()
    r2.title('Random Generator')
    r2.geometry('350x300')
    r2.resizable(False, False)
    L1 = Label(r2, text='Welcome to My Random Generator!!').grid(row=1, column=1)
    L2 = Label(r2, text= edata).grid(row=3, column=1).grid(rowspawn=3, sticky=S)
    L2.config(width=200)
    B1 = Button(r2, text="Browse", command=Directory)
    B1.grid(rowspan=3, sticky=S)
    B2 = Button(r2, text="Randomize", command=Generator)
    B2.grid(rowspan=3, sticky=S)
    r2.mainloop

def Directory():
    global filename
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Excel Files", ".xlsx"),("All files","*.*")))
    pathlabel = Label(r2)
    pathlabel.config(text=(filename))
    pathlabel.grid(columnspan=2)
    pathlabel.pack()

def Generator():
    global edata
    global sheet
    global workbook
    with open(filename)as a:
        filelocation = (filename)
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filelocation)
        sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
        for col in range(sheet.nrows):
            edata = print[sheet.pop(sheet.random.cell.value(0, col))]
```

Comment: *Also I would kindly accept any suggestions for improvement of my current code thank you :)*.... Use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead for this purpose..

Comment: None of your functions are ever executed. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I'd recommend edit and removing a lot of the code that isn't directly related to the problem at hand (namely "edata"). @HarshitSeksaria is also correct that you'll likely have better feedback on Code Review than here.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for you time ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not how the [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#the-global-statement) keyword works... `global` just tells your function to look up the variable in the global namespace (instead of the local namespace of your function).

this would work:

```
N = None

def f():
    global N
    print(N)
```

without defining `N` first (or setting it inside your function) it will not.

this would also work:

```
def f():
    global N
    N = 5
    print(N)
```

(and it would spill `N` to your global namespace).

in any case: you have to set `N` (or `edata` in your case) before you try to read its value.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `edata` doesn't have a value. It needs to be defined before calling it.

Comment: edata = print[sheet.pop(sheet.random.cell.value(0, col))]

Comment: Yes I see. You are trying to call it from a different function.

Comment: Define it before you are calling it. check this link out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: thats why theres a global to use that variable in another function

Comment: Define it before calling it as in bring the function it is being defined in before the function you are calling it. Maybe I should have been more clear

Comment: Dude theres already globals
Well thanks for the help anyways:

Comment: Your using the globals incorrectly but check out the link i sent to use them properly.